# How to extract individual object from an ajax callback

Tags: ajax, json

I am getting back the following from an AJAX call which exactly matches the syntax in my manual:

```
    var data = {        
    coach100:   {
        PID: '23169',
        POrt: '11'
        }, 

    coach200:   {
        PID: '23170',
        POrt: '11'
        } 
        };
```

Now I want to extract one piece of data. The manual syntax is:

```
    data.coach100.PID
```

but the Firebug console says: "TypeError: data.coach100 is undefined"

How to format the data in the variable "data" so that it can be extracted using dot syntax?

Comment: data.coach100.PID looks right to me. Where are you calling it from? it might be a different issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This runs just fine in JSfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/GWFe9/

My guess is that you're defining and calling data in the wrong place.

If you're calling your data outside of the success of the ajax but also defining it there you're going to have a bad time.

try adding var data; to the top of your doc so its a global variable - then when you get the success from ajax define your data like this -

```
data = {        
    coach100:   {
        PID: '23169',
        POrt: '11'
        }, 

    coach200:   {
        PID: '23170',
        POrt: '11'
        } 
        };
```

then you can call it at any time after it's been loaded!

Comment: Drew, why is 'PID' black and 'POrt' blue in both of our code examples? This usually warns of a punctuation error, if two items which have the same function are different colors in a code editor.

Comment: Instead of that line I had had 'alert(data)' and it looked so complete, that I thought it must already be usable by javascript.